# Несколько форм в одной строке

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста сделать формы на одном уровне по горизонтали, вот пока что есть (Я новичок)

Comment: Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Вы уверены,что вам необходимо две формы в одну строку, а не два поля одной формы?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<div>
   <div style="float: left;">
      <form><input type="text">..<form>
   </div>
   <div style="float: right;">
      <form><input type="text">..<form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row > div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: .66em;
  position: relative;
}

label.required::after {
  content: "*";
  color: #c00;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
      <label for="" class="required">Дата зачисления </label>
      <input type="date" />
  </div>
  <div>
      <label for="">Дата приказа </label>
      <input type="date" />
  </div>
</div>
```